# Unable to create application data (Too many open files)

Tags: java, spring-boot, jetty, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to connect from client to server to get data, this happens often and continuously about once a minute with a large number of requests, resulting in too many open files.

Although I closed the connections after the results.
I also tried increasing the open files limit from 1024 to higher (ulimit -a) but from time to time I keep getting this error again.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:876)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1623)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at com.bot.auto.config.SimpleCorsFilter.doFilter(SimpleCorsFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1711)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1347)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1678)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1249)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.run(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Connection.produce(HTTP2Connection.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Connection.onFillable(HTTP2Connection.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.HTTP2Connection$FillableCallback.succeeded(HTTP2Connection.java:348)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:781)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:917)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

```
13-08-2021 11:42:37.291 [qtp507911745-12772] WARN 
                org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.failed - java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unable to create application data
13-08-2021 11:42:37.309 [qtp507911745-13-acceptor-0@f539e77-ServerConnector@64c63c79{SSL,[ssl, alpn, h2, http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8085}] WARN 
                o.e.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.handleAcceptFailure - 
java.io.IOException: Too many open files
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.accept(ServerConnector.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector$Acceptor.run(AbstractConnector.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:781)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:917)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: keystore.p12 (Too many open files)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.bot.auto.utils.AccessBOUtils.createTlsV2HttpClient123(AccessBOUtils.java:496)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public CloseableHttpClient createTlsV2HttpClient() throws Exception {
    KeyStore keyStore = null;
    SSLContext sslcontext = null;
    keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("keystore.p12"));
    keyStore.load(inputStream, "123456".toCharArray());
    sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom().loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, "123456".toCharArray()).build();
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory f = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext, new String[] { "TLSv1","TLSv1.1","TLSv1.2"}, null,
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
    Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
            .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory())
            .register("https", f)
            .build();
    ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy myStrategy = new ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy() {
        public long getKeepAliveDuration(HttpResponse response, HttpContext context) {
            // Honor 'keep-alive' header
            HeaderElementIterator it = new BasicHeaderElementIterator(
                    response.headerIterator(HTTP.CONN_KEEP_ALIVE));
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                HeaderElement he = it.nextElement();
                String param = he.getName();
                String value = he.getValue();
                if (value != null && param.equalsIgnoreCase("timeout")) {
                    try {
                        return Long.parseLong(value) * 1000;
                    } catch(NumberFormatException ignore) {
                    }
                }
            }
            HttpHost target = (HttpHost) context.getAttribute(
                    HttpClientContext.HTTP_TARGET_HOST);
            if ("www.botautobo.com".equalsIgnoreCase(target.getHostName())) {
                // Keep alive for 5 seconds only
                return 5 * 1000;
            } else {
                // otherwise keep alive for 30 seconds
                return 30 * 1000;
            }
        }

    };
    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry);
    cm.setMaxTotal(2000000);cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);
    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectionRequestTimeout(30000)
            .setConnectTimeout(30000).setSocketTimeout(60000).build();
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).setSSLSocketFactory(f).setConnectionManager(cm).setKeepAliveStrategy(myStrategy).build();
    
    return client;
}

private Map<String, String> mapBalance;

public Map<String, String> getBalance() {
    mapBalance = new HashMap<String, String>();
    try {
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = createTlsV2HttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("example.com/api..");
        httpGet.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        httpGet.setHeader("User-Agent", "Other Other");
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
        int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        LOGGER.info("statusCode: "+ responseCode);
        if(responseCode == 200) {
            String stringResponse = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringResponse);
                JSONObject jsonObjectD = jsonObject.getJSONObject("d");
                LOGGER.info("jsonObjectD getBalance:"+jsonObjectD);
                mapBalance.put("availableBalance", jsonObjectD.get("availableBalance").toString());
                mapBalance.put("demoBalance", jsonObjectD.get("demoBalance").toString());
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                LOGGER.error("Error getBalance have statusCode200 : {}",ex);
            }
            
        } else if(responseCode == 401){
            ///...
        } else if(responseCode == 403){
            //...
        }
        httpclient.close();
        response.close();
        EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
        if(httpclient != null || response != null) {
            httpclient.close();
            httpclient = null;
            response.close();
            response = null;
        }
//            EntityUtils.consumeQuietly(response.getEntity());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.error("Error getBalance: {}",ex);
    }
    return mapBalance;
}
```

Comment: You should close everything as soon as you can (e.g. `inputStream`). `try-with-resources` helps you with this.

Comment: And verify that your environment has a sane "open files" limit before you start java (see `ulimit -a` on unix environments).